# SSIS OLEDB Command DataType error

Tags: ssis, oledb, oledbcommand

I am not able to change the Data type of a parameter in the advanced editor options of OLEDB Command transformation. Every time I change it, upon reopening the Advanced Editor, the change is reverted.

[image: See the screenshot]

Here, if I change the data type from string [DT_STR] to Unicode string [DT_WSTR], upon reopening it is changed back to string [DT_STR] again. Is there any way to make change the data type value here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change it there. The value is fixed. You can change it on the output side. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the input type. Let it flow as it is and change it on the output side of things. I believe that should be pretty easy to achieve.